# How to do LEFT OUTER JOIN but only return first row if matched?

Tags: mysql, sql

The schema is pretty straightforward:

- A Business has many Customers
- A Customer may have zero to many Phones
- A Customer may have zero to many Emails
- Both Phone and Email tables have an 'IsPrimary' bool field to reflect the primary one to use

So I tried this but that WHERE clause will effectively eliminate the LEFT OUTER JOIN's ability to return records where there are zero Phones or Emails. If I leave the WHERE out I get multiple Phone/Emails when I just want the IsPrimary one (if exists). How do I tackle this best? Thanks

```
    SELECT b.BusinessName, c.FirstName, c.LastName, p.PhoneNumber, e.EmailAddress,
    FROM Business b 
    INNER JOIN Business b ON c.BusinessId = b.BusinessId 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Phone p ON p.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Email e ON e.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
    WHERE p.IsPrimary = true AND e.IsPrimary = true
```

PS: this is MySQL 5.6

Comment: just add a `limit 1` at the end

Comment: The `WHERE` clause is silently converting the outer joins into inner joins. Put those predicates in the corresponding `ON` clauses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition should be moved to `ON` clause:

```
SELECT b.BusinessName, c.FirstName, c.LastName, p.PhoneNumber, e.EmailAddress,
FROM Business b 
INNER JOIN Business b ON c.BusinessId = b.BusinessId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Phone p ON p.CustomerId = c.CustomerId AND p.IsPrimary = true
LEFT OUTER JOIN Email e ON e.CustomerId = c.CustomerId AND e.IsPrimary = true
```

Comment: Ahhhh of course, that makes sense as it operates on that outer join statement only. Thank you for the help